# Text-correlation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, correlation

I have three coloumns in my table, all containing text. I want to calculate a correlation between coloumn A and B, and A and C. How can I do this, and can I do it within MySQL?

For example, I can have the values

('Hello world', 'ello world', 'Good bye'), ('Hello world', 'H e l l o', 'Bye world')

Cheers

Nik